# The server responded with a status of 502 (Bad Gateway)

Tags: c#, .net

I have below API which generates numbering, and stores in a list then convert it into data table and then finally passed to UI as StringBuilder to generate in CSV. the issue is when I give a command for 20 lacs on server (IIS) it gives 502 error but it smoothly generates on local host ( time taking to generate 20 lacs numbering around 10 to 14 mins on local host.)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetNumbering([FromBody] NumberingRequest request)
{
    try
    {
        var details = numberingtools.GetNumbering(request);

        if (details.Count() > 0)
        {

            return Ok(new { ResponseCode = "200", ResponseMessage = "Record Found", Details = details });
        }
        else
        {
            return Ok(new { ResponseCode = "200", ResponseMessage = "Record Found", Details = details, totalRows = 0 });
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Ok(new { ResponseCode = "404", ResponseMessage = "Something Went Wrong", ErrorDetails = ex.Message });
    }
}
```

I have used Kestral in program.cs but not worked

```
.UseKestrel(c => { c.AddServerHeader = false; c.Limits.KeepAliveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10); })
```

I have also used API live timeout code but not working...

Comment: Have you checked the executionTimeout configuration in IIS site settings?

Comment: I am not able to find the execution timeout configuration, where can I check, it is not visible

Comment: I have checked, and it was set to 1800 sec i.e. 30 mins

Comment: So, my other guess will be IIS recycling the application. Check the recycling configuration. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/recycling/